# GCP Api Gateway with Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-cloud-api-gateway

I'm trying to set up GCP Api Gateway for my Cloud Run hosted containers but I' getting some errors regarding Firebase Authentication.

In the api spec, I copied what is published in the api gateway guide

```
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/{{ project_id }}"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "{{ project_id }}"
```

and added the security entry in the endpoints path

```
security:
   - firebase: []
```

When I make a request through the Api Gateway, some additional headers are added to the request that is proxied to the Cloud Run service, such as `x-apigateway-api-userinfo`, `x-forwarded-authorization` and `authorization`

Then, in the Cloud Run service, I have to use Firebase Admin sdk to verify the token passed and identify the user who is making the request. That's where the problem begins, when I try verifying any of this header's token, I get an error: "FirebaseAuthError: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token."

Am I doing anything wrong? How can I decode the auth token passed to the Api Gateway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the validity of the token is already done by the API Gateway.

x-apigateway-api-userinfo is not the JWT, it's a base64 encoded json containing the users information. Decode it and you should be golden.

Comment: Also here is an article that might help (written in go) https://dev.to/amammay/gcp-api-gateway-firebase-authentication-34j7